# Create object and display it in same page with htmx

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, htmx

The function I am trying to implement is that, when the form is submitted in the create view, I would like to display the created object beneath it without the page refreshing. I know the way to implement this is through HTMX. The object that is being created is a key which is unique and gets randomly generated. However it does not work properly. Right now, first time clicking the button it creates a key and displays it but the second time it tries to show the previous key and because it already exists it is not unique and therefore it shows nothing.

This is the model

```
class Key(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, default=get_random_string(length=10), unique=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("key", kwargs={"id": self.id })
```

I have two views, a create view and a detail view, I would have liked to used CBV but I can't get my head around how I would implement that, so I am sticking to function based views. Right now the views are looking like this

```
@login_required
def key_create_view(request):
    form = CreateKeyForm(request.POST or None)

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.save()
        key_url = reverse('key', kwargs={'id':obj.id})
        if request.htmx:
            context = {
                 "object": obj,
                 "key_url": key_url
             }
            return render(request, "base/components/key.html", context)
        #return redirect(obj.get_absolute_url())
    return render(request, "base/form.html", context)  



@login_required
def key_detail_hx_view(request, id=None):
    if not request.htmx:
        raise Http404
    try:
        obj = Key.objects.get(id=id)
    except:
        obj = None
    if obj is  None:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong")
    context = {
        "object": obj
    }
    return render(request, "base/components/key.html", context)
```

In the template have I built it like this

```
<form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div id="key" class="text-center">
                <button hx-post="{{key_url}}" hx-target="#key" hx-swap="beforeend" type="submit">Create new key</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I would like it to generate a new key each time the button is pressed and replace the previous one. Does anybody know how I can implement that?

**EDIT**
These are my urls

```
path('createkey', key_create_view, name='create_key'),
    path('createkey/<int:id>', key_detail_hx_view, name='key')
```

This is the form

```
class CreateKeyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Key
        fields = ()
```

So it is an empty form, just to create the object.

Comment: Could you also share the `get_random_string()` function? If you want to replace the previously generated key with the new one, why did you set the swapping method to appending (`beforeend`)?

Comment: @dauros the `get_random_string()` is imported from `from django.utils.crypto`. I was not sure what to set it to, what do you reckon I should change it to?

Comment: If you want to replace content with HTMX, you need to have a dedicated element for it and use the default `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` swapping method. Could you share the relevant URL definitions? Your form target is `{{key.url}}` but I don't know why. The target endpoint of a post form should be the form handling view. Furthermore I don't see this `key` object in the context variable, where do you pass it to the template? And what is the definition of `CreateKeyForm`?

Comment: @Dauros Okey, I have now shared both the form and the URLS. I misspelled the `{{key_url}}`, I used '.' instead of '_', this is however defined in the createview. I use `obj` instead of `key` in the create view to make it more general, this is passed in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key creating form's `hx-post` endpoint should be the `key_create_view` not the key displaying view. Actually, on the form page `{{ key_url }}` is empty. Furthermore, since you want to show only the last generated key, the swapping method should be the default `innerHTML`, so HTMX will replace the content inside the `#key` div with the new one.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="text-center">
    <button hx-post="{% url 'create_key' %}" hx-target="#key" type="submit">Create new key</button>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- HTMX will swap the returned key here -->
<div id="key"></div>
```

### Edit:

The duplicate key error is caused by the wrong approach to add a dynamic default value. If you actually call the function (`get_random_string(10)`) it will be executed once and each key will receive the same random string. You need to pass the function as a reference, so each time Django creates a new model, it will call this function, creating a new random string. Since `get_random_string` needs a parameter, we need to create a small wrapper function.

```
def get_default_random_string():
    return get_random_string(length=10)


class Key(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, default=get_default_random_string, unique=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but it still does not create a new object when the button is pressed the second time, it still tries to display the last key which is not possible because it is not unique. I get the following error in the command line `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`

Comment: You're right, that's a different issue, see my edited answer for the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, both for your time and effort! This solved my problem and now it works exactly as I wanted it to work like.